# Map XML(of same tag name) to Java Object

Tags: java, xml, spring

I got a requirement that I have to map my xml to java object without parsing it, but the problem is like that in xml tag names would be same, for example,

```
 <response>
    <employee>
    <name>Sharique</name>
    <name>24</name>
    <name>India</name>
    </employee>
    </response>
```

and class would be like this

```
public class Employee{
private String empName;
private int age;
private String country;

//getters and setters
}
```

Please help!!
If it can be done using spring than that would be very nice

Comment: read about jaxb. It is what you are looking for.

Comment: Can you provide me of some link regarding this...that wud be helpful and can we achieve this using spring??

Comment: create xml schema of your xml and than use xjc command [available with jdk] to generate equivalent java classes of that. once classes generated you can use jaxb marshaller and unmarshaller to get object from xml and vice versa. you can get lot of examples on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you leverage EclipseLink MOXy as your JAXB (JSR-222) provider then you can use our `@XmlPath` extension for this use case.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Employee{
    @XmlPath("name[1]/text()")
    private String 

    @XmlPath("name[2]/text()")
    private int age;

    @XmlPath("name[3]/text()")
    private String country;

    //getters and setters
}
```

**For More Information**

I have written more about the `@XmlPath` extension on my blog:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html

Answer (score 0):

Not required, As per javax.xml.bind.annotation you can do like below,

```
@XmlElement(name="name")
    private String empName;
```

So now the **empName** in your java class will be mapped to **name** attribute in your XML.

and your XML should not have 'name' as name for all attributes. it cannot differentiate, so you need to use different tags in your XML for other elements like age and so on ans map accordingly as i stated above in your POJO.

Comment: But that's what the challenge is...this is what my requirement is because the response as xml I am getting is in that format onl

Answer (score 0):

You really got some weird XML there. I thing data binding will not help in this case, but you can do it with [data projection](http://xmlbeam.org). (Disclosure: I'm affilited with that project)

```
public class ParseResponse {

public interface Employee {
    @XBRead("./name[1]")
    String getName();

    @XBRead("./name[2]")
    int getAge();

    @XBRead("./name[3]")
    String getCountry();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Employee> employees = new XBProjector().io().url("res://response.xml").evalXPath("//employee").asListOf(Employee.class);
    for (Employee employee:employees) {
        System.out.println(employee.getName());
        System.out.println(employee.getAge());
        System.out.println(employee.getCountry());
    }
    }
}
```

this program prints out

```
Sharique
24
India
```

if you fix the XML closing tags.