# What is @XmlPath analog in jackson?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, jackson, moxy

With `org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath` it is possible to [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28104772/map-xmlof-same-tag-name-to-java-object) same elements into separate class fields. It there analog annotation for jackson?

Answer (score 0):

The Analog is [Elastic Path's JSON Unmarshaller](https://github.com/elasticpath/json-unmarshaller)

Given the example in the question about XmlPath, I created the following example:

Input Json

```
{ "response": 
  { "employee": [ 
    {"name":"Sharique"}, 
    {"name":24}, 
    {"name":"India"}
  ]}
}
```

Target POJO:

```
public class Employee
{
    @JsonPath("$.response.employee[0].name")
    private String empName;
    @JsonPath("$.response.employee[1].name")
    private int age;
    @JsonPath("$.response.employee[2].name")
    private String country;

    public String getEmpName() { return empName; }
    public void   setEmpName(String empName) { this.empName = empName; }
    public int    getAge() { return age; }
    public void   setAge(int age) { this.age = age; }
    public String getCountry() { return country; }
    public void   setCountry(String country) { this.country = country; }
}
```

Invocation:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String json = "{ \"response\": { \"employee\": [ {\"name\":\"Sharique\"}, {\"name\":24}, {\"name\":\"India\"}] }}";

    try {
        JsonUnmarshaller unmarshaller = new DefaultJsonUnmarshaller();
        Employee emp = unmarshaller.unmarshal(Employee.class, json);
        System.out.println(emp.getEmpName() + " " + emp.getAge() + " " + emp.getCountry());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Output:

```
Sharique 24 India
```